# How to split a polygon shapefile into small polygons using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, google-earth-engine

I have a polygon shapefile and want to divide them into very small regions using python.

This is being done as Google Earth Engine does not download data over large areas, hence I want to divide the whole shapefile and download the data individually. I realise there is an option to export data to google cloud/drive but it is not what I'm looking for.

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET').filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-06-01','2021-10-31'));
Fuel_Moisture_1000Hr = dataset.select('fm1000').median() 
geemap.ee_export_image(Fuel_Moisture_1000Hr, filename=os.path.join(export_path, 'fm_1000hr.tif'), scale=4638.3, region=roi, file_per_band=False)
```

The ROI is large and I want to divide them into small regions and run the above command in a `for` loop.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this using the Google Earth Engine Python API?  In any event, no matter which Python library you wish to ask about, please include a code attempt.

Comment: [Create a grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269243/creating-polygon-grid-using-geopandas), intersect it with your polygons

Comment: Thanks @BERA it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use QGIS tool for this task: [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer)

If you want to use python specifically, you can call this tool in `pyqgis`.

Comment: I want to split them in a python script, pyqgis I think pyqgis is not a very good choice then as we can't directly import it