Plotting square grid using GeoPandas
I have Lat and long data and I want to plot as a square grid to cover the boundary. So how can I do using GeoPandas?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269243/creating-polygon-grid-using-geopandas

Create a point grid, buffer it with square buffers:
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

#Create a point dataframe from a list of long and lats
coords = [[14.98, 58.89],[14.87, 58.84],[15.24, 58.78],[14.94, 59.21],
          [14.24, 58.71],[14.58, 59.27],[14.79, 59.17],[14.8, 59.04],
          [14.11, 58.82],[15.41, 59.26],[15.49, 59.1],[14.39, 59.04]]

points = gpd.points_from_xy(x=[i[0] for i in coords], y=[i[1] for i in coords])
point_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=points, crs=4326)

#Reproject to a projected coordinate system with units in meters
point_df = point_df.to_crs(point_df.estimate_utm_crs())

#Create the grid
grid_size = 10000 #Size of the square sides
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = point_df.total_bounds #Extract the extent of the point df
xcoords = np.arange(start=xmin, stop=xmax+grid_size, step=grid_size) #Create a range of x coordinates
ycoords = np.arange(start=ymin, stop=ymax+grid_size, step=grid_size) #And y
grid_coords = np.array(np.meshgrid(xcoords, ycoords)).T.reshape(-1,2) #All combinations of the x and y coord: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays

#Create grid center points from the coordinates
grid_points = gpd.points_from_xy(x=grid_coords[:,0], y=grid_coords[:,1])
#Buffer them with square cap style to create square polygons
grid_squares = [pnt.buffer(distance=grid_size/2, cap_style="square") for pnt in grid_points]

grid_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=grid_squares, crs=point_df.crs)

ax = grid_df.boundary.plot(zorder=1, color="black", figsize=(10,10))
point_df.plot(ax=ax, zorder=2, color="red")

#pointdf = point_df.to_crs(4326) #Reproject back to the original crs


